# Dynamic role based security in Tabular Model. (DAX)

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

If you could suggest me an approach to solve my Role Based security problem, it will be helpful.
I have Model consist of tables, Product (Product ID, Product Name), User(User ID, Username) and a mapping table Product_User (ProductID, UserID).
Product_User is Many to Many mapping table (a product can be associated to any number of user and a user can have any no. of association to Product as well). The role based security will get interesting, if try to show the Product name which are mapped to the current user (function :Username ()).
In my Roles, the dax formula I have written is not working. The formula is 
=Product[Product Id]=LOOKUPVALUE(Product_User[CID],Product_User[UID],LOOKUPVALUE(User[UserID],User[UserName],LOWER(USERNAME())))

Any help is very much useful

Comment: It is resolved now. Thanks! the formula lookup can filter with multiple criteria. using that completed.